# Phoenix + React Native and Redux: Where should I put channel object?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, phoenix-framework

I have a component called `PlatformMain` that currently depends on a global `channel` object from Phoenix defined inside of the component's file.

```
let channel;
let socket = new Socket("...", {params: {token: window.userToken}});
socket.connect();


class PlatformMain extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.connectUser();
  }

  connectUser() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    channel = socket.channel("user_pool:" + user.email, { app: APP });
    this.setupChannel();
  }

  setupChannel() {
    channel.join()
      .receive("ok", () => { console.log("Successfully joined call channel") })
      .receive("error", () => { console.log("Unable to join") })

    channel.on("match_found", payload => {
      ...
    });
    ...
}
```

If the user presses a button, I'd like that to dispatch an action as well as push a message to the channel.

```
  onPress() {
    console.log("APPROVE_MATCH");
    const { peer, waitForResponse } = this.props;

    approveMatch(peer);
    channel.push("approve_match", { // <------ want to put this somewhere else
      "matched_client_email": peer.email,
    });
  }
```

My question is, if I want to "reduxify" the channel.push call, where should I put it? It feels weird not having the `channel.push(...)` somewhere else since it's an API call. I was going to put it in a saga using redux-saga like so:

```
function* approveMatch(action) {
  const peer = action.payload.peer;
  channel.push("approve_match", { // <------- but how would I get the same channel object?
    "matched_client_email": peer.email,
  });
}

export default function* watchMatchingStatus() {
  yield takeEvery(matchingStatusActions.APPROVE_MATCH, approveMatch);
}
```

But wouldn't I need to point to the same channel object? How would I do that? If I put the initialization of the `channel` in its own file and I export and import it in multiple places, wouldn't it execute the file multiple times (and consequently join the channel multiple times)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the initialization of `channel` in its own file and safely import multiple times, the evaluation of the module only happens once. You can check [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-module-records) for confirmation:

> Do nothing if this module has already been evaluated. Otherwise, transitively evaluate all module dependences of this module and then evaluate this module.